# How to resolve template loop detected issue in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

Recently, I have installed `MediaWiki version 1.22` onto my local machine.
I have added few templates pages, when I'm trying to use them, it displays

`Template loop detected:`

[image: template loop detected]

I also deleted some of old pages using admin login, but still it showing the same problem.

Comment: Please include the sources of your templates and how you're using them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Template loops happen when two templates are [transcluding](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help%3aTemplates#Usage) each other, for example

Template:Foo contains
`{{bar}}`

while Template:Bar contains
`{{foo}}`

This can happen also through intermediate templates, e.g. foo transcludes bar which transcludes baz which transcludes foo.

Since I haven't seen your templates I can't tell what exactly is wrong, but the general advice is to look at your templates' source.

Comment: I am using a ```{{Infobox university
| name        = University of XYZ
| native_name = Universiti XYZ
}}``` in one of the wiki page and create the template page ```Template:Infobox university``` with wikicode ```{{Infobox university
| name           = 
| native_name    = 
}}``` after that I am seeing that error. Along with that I have deleted the ```Template:Infobox``` page

Comment: Well, you're transcluding that template from itself then:) You need to add actual template code to it, not an invocation.

Comment: Where I can get the template code for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Infobox_university#Syntax

Comment: @made_in_india That's the syntax to *use* the template, not to declare it. For that, you'll have to look at [its source](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Template:Infobox_university&action=edit).